# Server Code working with Javascript in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to understand how we can interact server section of code with pure JS (or Jquery). I prepared two examples - Basically I want to hide h4( ) on clicking of button by user. First example works as expected but second one does not work as h4() is in renderUI( ) in server. I know this can be solved via observeEvent or shinyJS package but I am more interested to make it work with pure JS not running JS code in server.

**Example 1**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    h4("Testing"),
    actionButton("Disable", "Disable Element"),
    tags$script("
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#Disable').click(function(){
      $('h4').css('display', 'none');
      });
})")
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) { })
```

**Example 2**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    h4("Testing"),
    uiOutput("myfun"),
    tags$script("
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#Disable').click(function(){
      $('h4').css('display', 'none');
      });
})")
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) {
  
  output$myfun <- renderUI({
    
    tagList(
    actionButton("Disable", "Disable Element")
    )
    
  })
  
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to add an onclick event to the button itself.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    h4("Testing"),
    uiOutput("myfun"),
    tags$script("hideH4 = function() {$('h4').css('display', 'none');}")
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) {
  output$myfun <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      actionButton("Disable", "Disable Element", onclick="hideH4()")
    )
  })
})
```

Or add a document event hadler for the click and check the ID

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    h4("Testing"),
    uiOutput("myfun"),
    tags$script("
    $(document).click(function(evt) {
      if (evt.target.id=='Disable') {
         $('h4').css('display', 'none');
      }})")
    )
)

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) {
  output$myfun <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      actionButton("Disable", "Disable Element")
    )
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Your second solution works for me.  Just a question - console.log(evt.target) does not return anything in console? any reference for me please to read in detail about document event handler

Comment: I removed that. I forgot it was there.